# Two column layout in mPDF with a single line in between the columns

Tags: php, mpdf

I want a two-column layout in mPDF where the content should be placed within two columns when the first column ends, then go to the second column when. Both columns are filled. They go to the next page and do the same thing. A line should be between the columns. The content should not cross the line. I tried all possible methods but failed.

An image is attached as a sample of what I wanted; please help me.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bggBy.jpg)

Two-column layout with dynamic flow of content when the first column ends, then to the next column, then to the next page with the same two columns. I tried all possible things but was not successful.

Comment: You can use CSS columns in the HTML content that you pass to mPDF.

Comment: Could you please help me with it give a sample code

Comment: Please provide a sample code I'd you can sir

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _I tried all possible things_ I assume you are referring to PHP code that you tried. I suggest that you [edit] your question and post the [PHP] code that you tried and also explain what result that code gave you and why it is not the result that you wanted.